# Google Charts & MySQL Timestamp handling questions

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I have a logging device to a MySQL database, from which I would like to read several hundred rows from, and create a Google chart with.

I can't seem to find a good way to translate the MySQL timestamp data into timeofday column type for the Google chart data array.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes

I have developed a PHP that can echo the data that I wish, however I am stuck with MySQL, or Unix timestamp formats.  PHP file:

```
<?php 
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "readuser", "***", "***");
            /* check connection */
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
                exit();
            }
            /* Select queries return a resultset */
            if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ID, Timestamp, temp FROM temperature ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5")) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                $dataset1[] = array($row['Timestamp'],$row['temp']);
                }

            /* encode array to JSON for JavaScript */
            echo json_encode($dataset1); 


            /* free result set */
            $result->close();
            }

        ?>
```

Example of the above php execution:

```
[
["2018-08-03 17:01:33","80.60"],
["2018-08-03 17:01:23","81.05"],
["2018-08-03 17:01:13","80.60"],
["2018-08-03 17:01:03","81.05"],
["2018-08-03 17:00:53","81.05"]
]
```

What I believe that Google charts would like to see is something more like:

```
[
[[17, 01, 33],80.60],
[[17, 01, 23],81.05],
[[17, 01, 13],80.60],
[[17, 01, 03],81.50],
[[17, 00, 50],81.05]
]
```

Here is the main PHP file that the data will go into (ajax to access the json data php file, and updating the chart drawing at setInterval):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      /* declare variable for json data */
    var chardata;
    /* ajax to pull mysql data via php file */
    function chartdataquery() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'/mysql/chartdata.php',
            type:'POST',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function (results) {
                chartdata = (results);
                } 
            });
         };
    /* Set the chartdata update frequency */
    updatequeryInterval = setInterval(chartdataquery,10000);

/* drawing the chart at the setInterval duration, at the end of the function */
    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');

      data.addRows(chartdata);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Temperature',
          subtitle: 'updated every 10 seconds'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));


      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="linechart_material" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is that correct, and is that something I can accomplish with the MySQL query or in PHP, or Javascript?  What is my best route to make the array Google chart compliant for timeofday?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try loading the php array like this...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $dataset1[] = array(array((int) date_format(new DateTime($row['Timestamp']), 'H'), (int) date_format(new DateTime($row['Timestamp']), 'i'), (int) date_format(new DateTime($row['Timestamp']), 's')),$row['temp']);
}
```

for the above to work, you'll need to change the google column type to...

```
data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
```

Comment: I get this error out of the php file with that code:

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface